# Extract date from string with separator char in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, substring

I want to extract the date from a column having the format: `"text #date" where date is of format "dd.mm.yyyy"` and the separator char is `#`. Also, the date is not included in all records or the records are null. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your date format contains 10 characters; so check the 11th character from the end to see if it is the separator character and, if so, extract the date otherwise return `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR( your_column, -11, 1 ) = '#'
       THEN TO_DATE( SUBSTR( your_column, -10 ), 'dd.mm.yyyy' )
       ELSE NULL
       END
FROM   your_table
```

If the date can have single digit days/months so the date will not be exactly 10 characters then:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN INSTR( your_column, '#', -1 ) > 0
       THEN TO_DATE( SUBSTR( your_column, INSTR( your_column, '#', -1 ) + 1 ), 'dd.mm.yyyy' )
       ELSE NULL
       END
FROM   your_table
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b5b050cc766996cb630c6f7058c1422)*

Answer (score 0):

You can extract date by below query as well:-

```
 select to_date (trim(substr(key1 ,instr(key1,'#',1) +1 )),'dd/mm/yyyy' ) date1 from test_table 
    where  instr(key1,'#') > 0;
```